# Access the index of a for loop in Python

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to read from a text file each line of from the file. It works. But actually I would like to add an index for each line.

I have the following code:

**views.py**:

```
def survey(request):

myFile = open(r'd:\work\Python\ps\psi\questions.txt', 'r')
out = myFile.readlines()

return render_to_response("questions.html", {'f' : out})
```

**questions.html**:

```
{%  for line in f %}

  #here I would like to add an index, for instance :
  # 1.Question1 text
  # 2.Question2 text
  {{ line }}<br>

{% endfor %}
```

I tried to use `enumarate(f)` using the following code:

```
{%  for index, line in enumerate(f) %}
            {{index }}.{{ line }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

But, it doesn't work. I get the error: `Could not parse the remainder: '(f)' from 'enumerate(f)'`.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't put python code in the templates, in Django you can use

```
{{ forloop.counter }}
```

For an index starting at 1, or

```
{{ forloop.counter0 }}
```

for 0-based index.

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for).

Comment: Got it. But I wonder what exactly is `forloop`? (is it a property or something?)

Comment: It's part of the django template language syntax, I think.